# Is my iPod Touch 2G supposed to be outputting audio over headphones and internal speaker simultaneously?

Tags: ipod-touch, headphones

I know this is an old device but I hope it's still okay to ask about it.

I got a 2nd gen (I think) 8GB iPod Touch from my partner last week. She forgot the pin so I just restored it in iTunes.

I loaded some of my music onto it and noticed today that the music was also playing from the internal speaker, *as well as* my headphones. Is this normal, or expected, behaviour for this device? It looks to be in great shape hardware wise (no external damage apart from the standard scratching of the back) and I haven't jailbroken it. It's running iOS 4.2.1.

Comment: Not normal. The headphone jack should switch out the internal speakers. Have you tried with another pair of headphones or earbuds?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, it happens on all my headphones. I also checked with some headphones that have just TRS and not TRRS (ie without mic) and it still occurs.